# Resolving hostnames querying multiple DNS servers

Tags: linux, dns, resolv.conf

We have two isolated private network domains `dc.example.com` and `cloud.example.com` and both of those have their own DNS servers.
But we have a client machine connected to both of those networks.
How do I route the queries for `*.dc.example.com` to first name server and `*.cloud.example.com` to second name server?

We have two options:

1. Making the other DNS zone as secondary and query to the first DNS server
2. Use DNS forwarder server to do conditional forwarding

Is there any other way to achieve this just from the client machine without the need to replicate the entire NS database as secondary or spinning up an additional forwarder. I tried with all the options of `resolv.conf` but unsuccessful

Comment: I think dnsmasq might do what you want

Comment: Why can you not use normal DNS delegation mecanisms? In `example.com` zone you just delegate each subzone to its own set of nameservers and let resolvers do their normal resolution mechanisms?